# matching the outputs of upsample and resample functions of matlab

Tags: matlab

i'm upsampling a signal from 100k to 30M samples using upsample function of MATLAB. But when i use resample function, the output is different.How can i use resample to get exact output like that of upsample function?

Comment: I'm not expert here but I think your example might help a bit. :)

Comment: Here out_I signal is Gaussain filtered.
out_I_up=upsample(out_I,5000);
xx=300*fir1(100,1/5000); % order N=100, cutoff frequency=1/300
out_i=filter(xx, 1, out_I_up);

Can't i replace it with??
out_i=resample(out_I,3000,1);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, as they do different things.

`upsample` just inserts zeros between your samples, while `resample` applies an anti-aliasing filter and then interpolates.

So for example, if your signal is `x=[1,1]`, `upsample(x,2)` will output `1,0,1,0`, while `resmaple(x,2,1)` outputs `1, 1.26, 1, 0.43`, which is the result of filtering and interpolation.

Comment: Here out_I signal is Gaussain filtered. 

out_I_up=upsample(out_I,5000); xx=300*fir1(100,1/5000); % order N=100, cutoff frequency=1/300 out_i=filter(xx, 1, out_I_up); 

Can't i replace it with?? out_i=resample(out_I,3000,1);

Comment: No, because your code in the comment includes only a low-pass filter (the anti-aliasing step), not the interpolation. In addition, it is probably not identical to the anti-aliasing applied by `resample`. Read the documentation to be sure